# How to list pages next to categories?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to build a small personal wiki with some kind of fast and easy tagging for each page.

My approach was to use categories as tags. On my main page I would like to list all categories and their corresponding pages next to them. In addition I want to list all pages which do not have any tags (categories) assigned to. Example:

```
Categorie A
Page_A1 Page_A2 Page_A3 ...

Categorie B
Page_B1 Page_B2 Page_B3 ...

...

Uncategorized
Page_1 Page_2 ...
```

I am looking for a solution where I dont have to explicitly specify each category.

Answer (score 1):

Use *[Category Tree](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryTree)* extension (add `wfLoadExtension( 'CategoryTree' );` to your `LocalSettings.php`, the extension is bundled with *MediaWiki*).

Then insert in your wikitext `<categorytree mode="pages" class="categories">All</categorytree>`. You can customise its appearance with CSS in *MediaWiki:Common.css*: `.categories { /* Your CSS */}`.

This example assumes that the categories that you want to show belong to some root category, in this case, *Category:All*.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question concerning non categorized pages. Also, is there a way to do this without a root category?

Comment: Also I would like to know, if there is a more natural approach maybe with tags, because for me it seems like a lot of work to add each category in a second step to a main category, but maybe im missing some tricks to do this fast...

Comment: I really doubt that you can easily list non-categorised pages. Even SMW will not help. I don't think that outputting a category hierarchy without a root category is possible, either, and I don't think that not having one is a good idea.

Comment: The extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiCategoryTagCloud will show *categorised* pages as a tag cloud.